# sequelize where clause on first level query with jsonb data type from included table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

This is what I'm trying to query:

```
Table1.findAndCountAll({
  include: [
    model: Table2,
    as: 'table2Alias'
    attributes: ['metadata'] // --> metadata is jsonb type: { level: 'senior' }
  ],
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { 'table2Alias.metadata.level': { [Op.iLike]: `%${queryText}%` } }
    ]
  }
});
```

I get this error from the code above:

> error: column Table1.table2Alias.metadata.level does not exist

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Sequelize.where and Sequelize.literal as shown below - it works for plain JSON in MySql.  You'll have to use somewhat different function(s) for JSONB in Postgres.

```
Table1.findAll({
   include: [{model: Table2, as : 'whatever'}],
   where : 
      Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('json_extract(metadata, \'$.level\')'), 
        {Op.like : '%senior%'})
})
```

Comment: I can't find any example on the docs that uses `table.jsonbField.jsonbFieldKey` query on where clause.

Answer (score 0):

In postgreSQL, the correct syntax to query JSONB field is to use `->>` operator. So the correct way in the `where` clause will be `table2Alias.metadata->>level`.